# How to get the auto incremented value in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I am using `Entity Framework 4.1 code first`.  I have a product table that has an Id column that is an auto incremented column.  When I add the the Product instance, how do I get this new id or the updated Product (returned with properties)?

My repository code:

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();

public void Insert(Product product)
{
     db.Products.Add(product);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After performing the insert look at the `product.Id` property (or whatever your id property is called). It will be updated by EF with the value assigned by the database.

Comment: what if I have to do it in a transaction which has more changes to be made before I can saveChanges? So a transaction would be, First add product, then save orderdetails with productId (auto increment). And only after both are done should we save changes. is that possible?

Comment: You could leave EF take care of setting the foreign keys: `db.Products.Add(product); orderDetail.Add(product); db.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail); db.SaveChanges();`